# How to call native android method(function) from javascript in android phongap application, without using webview?

Tags: java, javascript, android

How can I call a native android method(function), from javascript, in an Android phonegap application, without using webview concept.

Any one help me....

Which version of Cordovo supports this process?

Answer (score -1):

We can wrote custom plugin in phonegap that we can call from javascript.

below is the javascript line to call android function

```
exec(<successFunction>, <failFunction>, <service>, <action>, [<args>]);
```

add below code in config file

```
<feature name="<service_name>">
        <param name="android-package" value="<full_name_including_namespace>" />
    </feature>
```

below is the android class that needs to exptend Cordova Plugin class.

```
 public class CustomPlugin  extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
            public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        }
    }
```

Refer phonegap docs for [custom plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins) development